# Delete from table where multiple fields match select subquery result from other table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to delete an entry in a table where multiple fields match the results of another select subquery which takes data from another table.

query :

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE carriedby_circuit IN (SELECT
    circuit_id
FROM table2
WHERE circuit_name IN (SELECT
    t.sc_prod_service_id
FROM table3 t));
```

So I want to modify the query in such a way that if `circuit_id` form `table2` is present in `carriedBY_circuit` or in `CARRIED_CIRCUIT` columns of `table1`. it should delete the row from `table1`.

Comment: carriedby_circuit and CARRIEDBY_CIRCUIT should be the same column?

Comment: Can't you use joins instead of nested queries?

Comment: "is present in carriedby_circuit or in CARRIEDBY_CIRCUIT columns of table1." . You have two columns with the same name, one in lower case another in upper case?

Comment: Sorry my bad. we have two column with different name carriedBY_circuit  and CARRIED_CIRCUIT  column in table1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `merge`:

```
merge into table1 t1
  using (select t2.circuit_id from table2 t2 inner join table3 t3 on t2.circuit_name = t3.sc_prod_service_id) d
  on (d.circuit_id = t1.carriedby_circuit or d.circuit_id = t1.carried_circuit)
when matched then delete;
```

Comment: In this query we are checking only in carriedby_circuit column of t1. We have to check in other table also i.e. (CARRIED_CIRCUIT ) .so the the value can be either in carriedby_circuit  or in CARRIED_CIRCUIT.

Comment: So you can modify `on` condition to `on (d.circuit_id = t1.carriedby_circuit or d.circuit_id = t1.carried_circuit)`

Comment: Also I am trying to delete thousand/lac of record from DB. Ihave written Procedure for it                   create or replace
PROCEDURE SUBSREMOVAL AS 
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('----DELETING ROW FROM CIRCUIT TABLE START------' );
  DELETE from  table2 c where c.circuit_name in (select t.SC_PROD_SERVICE_ID from table3 t);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('----DELETING ROW FROM CIRCUIT TABLE END------' );
  COMMIT;
END SUBSREMOVAL;         I am getting ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded . Could you please suggest. because of the query is it locking the table ? or it's and oracle issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 3 tables and you are working with ids. Table1, table2 and table3. Your best approach is to join table2 with table3. Then query its results, to delete from table1.
Example:

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE table1.id IN(SELECT distinct id FROM tabel1 UNION SELECT ID as id    FROM tabel2);
```

PS: The union select will probably duplicate your Id´s, this is why I propose to use distinct.